# Where and when can Treasure Goblin rifts appear?

Tags: diablo-iii

Can you only find a Goblin Rift in Adventure Mode? Similarly, can treasure goblins found within Nephalem Rifts open up a Goblin Rift portal, or can only goblins found outside of Rifts open portals?

I already know that you have to be level 70, and that if a friend wants to enter they have to be nearby.

Comment: Voting to close because this refers to content which has not been released yet.

Comment: PTR has been out for several months and finally closed. People who have played PTR will know AND 2.1 has officially been released.

Comment: @shanodin Unless I'm missing something, Patch 2.1 is out now.

Comment: @cloudymusic not until the next maintenance is complete AFAIK.

Comment: @Samjus PTR/beta still counts as unreleased.

Comment: @shanodin Patch 2.1 is Live in North America.

Comment: @Samjus that'd explain it then. My version is still the previous version because I run the EU version of the game.

Comment: @shanodin No worries haha.  Hopefully you get yours soon.

Comment: @Samjus won't be able to play it until after work tomorrow! I really thought D3 patch releases were consistent across regions!

Comment: @shanodin PTR does not count as unreleased:  http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5539

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft thanks for providing the link - honestly I wasn't certain but thought I'd read on meta that PTR/beta counted as unreleased but apparently not. Seems like this is the question in which shanodin is wrong about everything!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this green post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/14058715775), you should only be level 70 and be in Adventure mode.

Quote:

> Goblin Realm:
>
> - Spawns from random Treasure Goblins at level 70 in Adventure mode
> - Only players present when the rift spawned can enter it

Please note, that only goblins found outside of the Rift will have a chance to open a portal.

Comment: [According to this post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/13272818008) it can happen in normal difficulty. It doesn't seem the level of difficulty affect it happening, maybe just frequency.

Comment: [Also, it doesn't happen in rifts so it seems](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/14059366012)

Comment: Can they spawn when you're in a rift?

Answer (score 2):

I have made it into several of these all from the same place. From what I can tell, it does not spawn inside of rifts nor in campaign mode.

The best place to find a goblin who will spawn the portal is in the Halls of Agony level 2. Take the waypoint there in adventure mode on any difficulty (difficulty affects gold drops), find the goblin, and cross your fingers. I have found the drop rate to be roughly 1 out of every 50 attempts.

Gold rates observed from the rifts (these rates include a bonus +100% from a community event).

- Hard: 4m
- Torment 1: 25m
- Torment 3: 37m
- Torment 4: 45m

Comment: Though note the gold rates are inflated by the 100% gold find event buff.

Comment: Correct, and also as a result of the current community event, goblins are spawning in pairs. I will make an edit to indicate the buff.

Comment: Halls of Agony guaranteed spot has been fixed.

Does anyone know if extra gold gear works on any of that? I recall reading a blue post that stated extra gold doesnt work on chest and urns, which is where 95% of the gold in this level comes from.

Comment: @Tom - HoA2 never had a single guaranteed spot, but it definitely wasn't "fixed". Sometimes the goblin is replaced by the Iron Maiden event. Extra gold gear does increase the yield of the goblin rift. I made it into one just last night, 2 man on t6 with no gold gear (still with community buff) and it was 80m.

Comment: @TravisJ By "definitely wasn't 'fixed'", I'm presuming you didn't see [this hotfix list](http://www.diablofans.com/blizz-tracker/topic/55938-patch-2-1-0-hotfixes-updated-8-29)?

Comment: @Beofett - I never state that it was 100% though. It is still the best place to farm these, and is still a very high %. That it was dropped from 100% to something in the 90s does not constitute it being nerfed in my opinion.

Comment: @TravisJ People were claiming it was 100% pre-nerf.  I have only found 1 pair of TGs out of half a dozen runs there since the nerf, which suggests it was nerfed **hard**, so I'm not convinced it is still the best place to farm, but I could have gotten exceptionally unlucky.

Comment: @Beofett - Yikes, that is bad luck. Sometimes rng is mean, but from what I have observed the goblins are there usually at least 4 of 5 times. I do it on T6, I wonder if the rate is different for different torment levels.

Comment: I just did 5 runs on T4.  2 times no Iron Maiden event was spawned, 3 times it was. But not a single TG.  I think perhaps you've just been very lucky since the hotfix.

Comment: @Beofett - Hm, perhaps the Halls are no longer a good place to farm :( I am sure there are others though, but the community event has sadly ended and they are no longer in pairs. Try the Halls of Lightning in Act II, if you take the Zoltun Kulle wp, run a little further in, and of the 3 portals the one on the right is the Halls of Lightning. I think that the HoL will either have a goblin or a resplendent chest at a high rate.

Comment: @TravisJ By guaranteed spot I didnt mean the goblin spawned at the same spot in Hoa2, I meant that Hoa2 was a spot where always a goblin spawned. And that has been fixed. If you get a goblin for 50 runs straight in a row, you can assume extreme luck, but also all of my clannies never had a run in that time where there was no goblin, so yes, that was a guaranteed spot.

Comment: @Tom - Yes, that is unfortunate. There are a few new places to find them though. The Core of Arreat, and just north of the waypoint in Northern Highlands.