# What are the requirements for the Greed portal to appear?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've killed hundreds of goblins, on multiple difficulties, in rifts, out of rifts... Bu no greed portal has opened yet.

I'm currently doing mainly rifts (I have a huge pile of rift fragments), so can these portals open in rifts? And do they require torment or above? Is there a level requirement before they can appear?

Comment: Probably your best bet is to put it on normal, and do act 1 bounties or something. You will encounter a fair amount of goblins while also having a chance at getting a roll on Royal Ring of Grandeur. While some may argue T6 is best for farming because you get the most gold while in the Vault, that is inconsequential. The gem itself will give millions of gold per minute on its own if you obtain it, and that should be your goal.

Comment: I'll do my bounties in T2 or T3 probably, I wanted to try T3 with my character anyway, HC adds some risks...

Comment: Similar post? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/182244/where-and-when-can-treasure-goblin-rifts-appear

Comment: @Samjus yes it is. Mine is a duplicate of yours. Didn't see that. I'll start the voting to close as duplicate chain.

Comment: @Arperum No worries. Just making sure you get a chance to see those answers as well :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't much known about the portal and the conditions under which it spawns. [This article](http://diablo.incgamers.com/blog/comments/vault-greeds-domain-qa) covers some information about Greed's Domain.

According to the article you'll need to be **at least level 70 and in adventure mode** for it to spawn. Also it won't spawn in (Greater) Nephalem Rifts but it can spawn in Whimsydale. Another thing to note: **There is no way of increasing the likeliness of spawning one**. Apparently it's completely random.

Now from personal experience: I've only been there once and while I wouldn't consider myself a hardcore diablo gamer I've killed about 150 Goblins since Patch 2.1.

So basically the only way to "Farm" these portals is farming treasure goblins.

Although the wiki states that most player get a Portal every 15-20 goblins, I'm personally really skeptical about the numbers, since I've only entered a portal once after 150 but maybe I'm just unlucky.

Comment: I think that always one spawning was a bug that got hotfixed IIRC.

Comment: @Arperum Hmm I'm not sure about it. I mean it could be that it's some kind of a hidden feature but right now I can just tell what the wiki says. I'll try it out as soon as I'm home.

Comment: [Treasure Goblins no longer have a 100% chance to spawn in Halls of Agony level 2 (8/28)](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/14057035811)

Comment: @Chippies Ok thanks. I guess I'll edit it out of the question and maybe the wiki can also use a update ;)

Comment: The only time I got a portal, that day, I got two within hours of each other. It's definitely RNG love and nothing else.

Answer (score 6):

The portal to The Vault will not spawn inside a Nephalem Rift (and Treasure Goblins don't spawn inside of Greater Rifts at all) and only players present in the game when the rift spawned can enter it.
Greed portals can only spawn in Level 70 Adventure mode on any difficulty.

Source [1](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/14058816153?page=2#36) and [2](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/14058715775)